# How to Extract a Zip file automatically after downloaded

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my web application, user can download a zip file, I want to extract that zip file automatically after downloaded.

I want create a batch file and want to execute that after download is complete in client machine, that will extract zip file automatically.

How to achieve in ASP.Net...

Comment: you want the zip to extracted on client's machine? How many files are present in a typical zip file? What is the size of your Zip file?

Comment: Would you hardcode where the zip file content will be extracted to if you are to achieve this? What 3rd party zip application are you intending to use? Your users will at some point have to do some manual work

Comment: @ViSu Yes, i want to extract in Client machine, it has 3-4 files

Comment: This is not going to work due to security breach on browser

Comment: Question is why do you want to do this in first place?

Comment: i got one way, we can create self extractor .exe, it'll extract file after executing .exe,  http://74.cz/en/make-sfx/

Answer (score 0):

It's almost impossible AMAIK. Because let's see what happens behind the scene. When you send a zip file to your client (User Agent, which in this case is browser), you simply send an HTTP response. From that point onward, you have no control over what happens.

Imagine it was possible. I would wrap up a virus in a zip file. Then I would persuade many victims to click a link for their free gift download, and after downloading I would make it unzip, then run and delete all your favorite songs. It's a security concern.

In general, HTTP and JavaScript are not allowed to do much with file system and host OS. Because you don't know what website you might step on while surfing the Internet.